# default function parameters in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have default function parameters in C# like we have in C++??

eg:

```
foo(int i = 10, int j  = 20) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Named and optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) are new in C# 4.0.

Comment: Just a little "Caveat": Optional Parameters get compiled into the caller, which can be problematic if the caller and callee are in two different assemblies as changes to the assembly containing the function don't get updated in the consumers unless they are recompiled. http://www.stum.de/2010/04/19/how-optional-parameters-work-why-they-can-be-dangerous-and-why-they-work-in-net-23-as-well/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, default parameters are in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only in C# 4.0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skolima. You're using the tools without checking the answers. It does answer the question, and it's the right answer. Though this answer could be improved.

Comment: @gdoron It's a duplicate of accepted answer and came later. Yes, the automatic comment is not fitting, that's my mistake, but this answer is not contributing anything.

Comment: @skolima, With that I agree. it can and  should be deleted by me... :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have C# 4 you can define your method twice, like this:

```
    public int MySillyMethod(int a)
    {
        return MySillyMethod(a, 1);
    }

    public int MySillyMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
```